# When the user did not fill up all the blanks or fill in wrongly, how to validate them and bring it back to the same form?

Tags: javascript, php, validation

This is by Newcustomer.php form whereby i click on the button next, it will proceed to the next form which is NewExpertise.php.

```
<form action = NewExpertise.php method="post">
    <?php
    include('CSS.php');
    include('DB.php');
    ?>
    <span class =wordtab>Name</span> <input name = newname id = 'newname' type='text'/> <br>
    <span class =wordtab>IC</span><input name = newic id = 'newic' type='text'/><br>
    <span class =wordtab>Number</span><input name = newnumber id = 'newnumber' type='text'/><br>
    <span class =wordtab>Nationality</span><input name = newnationality id = 'newnationality' type='text'/><br>
    <span class =wordtab>Status</span>
    <select name = 'newstatus' id = newstatus>
        <option value="Interested">Interested</option>
        <option value='Not Interested'>Not Interested</option>
    </select><br>

    <span class =wordtab>Remarks</span><input name = newremarks id = 'newremarks' type='text'/><br>
    <?php

    ?>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" id="Next" name="Next" value = "Next" >
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php';" value="Back to CRM" />
    </form>
```

This are my codes from newexpertise.php. It shows an sql to insert the new customer into my database. However i did a validation whereby if the textboxes are empty, i want it to go back to newcustomer.php and prompt them what fields are missing. If possible, how can i also validate fields whereby user and only type in numeric values in number textbox for example. Thank you so much.

```
    if(isset($_POST['Next']))
    {
        if($_POST['newname']==""||$_POST['newic']==""||$_POST['newnumber']==""||$_POST['newnationality']==""||$_POST['newstatus']==""||$_POST['newremarks']=="")
        {
            $message = "Please fill in the all the relevant data";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

        }

        else
        {

            $addquery = "INSERT INTO Particulars (Particulars_ID, Name, Identification_Number, Number, Nationality, Status, Remarks)
                    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$_POST[newname]', '$_POST[newic]','$_POST[newnumber]','$_POST[newnationality]','$_POST[newstatus]','$_POST[newremarks]')";
            if ($connect->query($addquery) === TRUE)
            {
                    $last_id = $connect->insert_id;


            }


            else 
            {
                echo "Error updating record: " . $connect->error;
            }

        }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp check javascript form validation. and php form validation http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:
Post your newcustomer formula to newcustomer.php. if it validates use

```
header("Location: http://test.com/nextpage");
```

To redirect the user. If validation fails use this code to write the users values back into the form

```
<input id="test" name="test" value="<?php    if(isset($_POST["test"])){echo $_POST["test"]}?>"/>
```

Comment: sorry i dont get it at all

Comment: Updated. Hope its easier to understand